# Stop keyboard directional navigation jumping out from one usercontrol to another

Tags: wpf, xaml

I’ve created very simple layout to show my problem. Basically I have a usercontrol(form) inside of another usercontrol(browse), now I want to be able to cycle through the form with tab and ctrl+tab, which it does. But I noticed that when I press an arrow key on any of the buttons (within the form) it jumps out of the form to the browse. So I set directional navigation for the keyboard to none, but it ignores it and still allows me to navigate with the arrow keys. How do I ensure that I cannot get out of that form with a keyboard?

Here is the xaml

```
<Window xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" Text="This is a browse" />
<wpfApplication1:Form Grid.Row="1"/>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Height="50" Width="300">move previous</Button>
    <Button Height="50" Width="300">move next</Button>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Form"
     Margin="30"
     Background="Gray"
     KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="Cycle"
     KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None"
     KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="First Name:" />
    <TextBox Width="500"
             Height="50"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Width="200"
            Height="50"
            Content="Save" />
    <Button Width="200"
            Height="50"
            Content="Close" />
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

`KeyboardNavigationMode` values:

> **None** - No keyboard navigation is allowed inside this container.

It means that no navigation with keys is allowed from outside of this container into this container.

What you are looking for is:

> **Contained** - Depending on the direction of the navigation, focus returns to the first or the last item when the end or the beginning of the container is reached, **but does not move past the beginning or end of the container**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so is there anyway to stop navigating completely by the arrow keys?

Comment: You can stop it at the window level set the `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Once"` on the root window. But you should not mess with that, directional navigation is a useful part of user interaction.

Comment: Thank you very much, it does exactly what I need. I don't need to navigate between buttons or off a form to a browse with arrow keys. So tabbing will cycle on the form, if the user wants to get out of the form, then tab to either save or cancel and press it. Fortunatelly, I can still navigate by DirectionalNavigation set to Once through listbox (just tested it). There is one thing I don't understand though, why it has to be set to Once, I tried to set it to None and it would not work. it does not make sense, but it works as it needs to with Once at window level, which then effects all forms :)

Answer (score 2):

You could add the handler for `PreviewKeyDown` for buttons to override arrow key events.

```
<Button PreviewKeyDown="Button_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

And code:

```
private void Button_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsDown && e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you wish to use a style to add handler for all of the buttons, you could use EventSetter to do that:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="Button_PreviewKeyDown"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, isn't there a better solution? because I have quite alot of places I would have to do something like this. I was thinking that there would a xaml solution which I could then move into a style, so its applied everywhere.

Comment: Well you can add same event for all of the buttons (or any other control), same as you would have to apply the same style, so it's not that much of a difference. While you could add attached property if you wish to preserve MVVM, it's just more code, but you can have a look at this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096621/wpf-disable-arrow-keys-on-tabcontrol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096621/wpf-disable-arrow-keys-on-tabcontrol)

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with answer above, yours works as well. But the other one allows me to set it in one single place (single xaml line as well), and I don't have to reference it anywhere :)